# Replacing decorator pattern to enforce creation order

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns

Trying to learn some new design patterns , I came across the following problem.
Let's say we have the following interface : GUI_ITEM.
We have some classes that implement it like : Canvas , TextView , ListView ..
The target is to add some extra behavior to those classes such as :
 Scrollbars , Title , Border ..

Now since we want to add a combination of behaviors to a given objects from the same interface , 
i'm guessing the right design to be used is a decorator .
This is the UML
[UML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVFKv.png)

(this is from a slide-show i'm learning from)

So usage would be something like this :

```
GUI_Item* gui = new Scrollbars(new Border(new Title(new Canvas() ) ) );
```

The following question arises ;
What if I want to enforce a creation order ?
Since the border can hide the scroll bar , or we added another feature which is created at the same spot of another feature , thus can hide it .

I'm trying to figure out which design pattern will be the best solution here and how to implement it since I want to remove this responsibility from the client.

I can't seem to think of a proper design pattern here ? maybe I should combine the decorator with another solution ?
I thought about adding a member to each decorator-class marking its hierarchy(such that objects with the same hierarchy cannot be created together)
in the displaying order but this seems like a bad solution (Because I feel like its violating the OPEN/CLOSED principle)

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think (as you may also be thinking) that Decorator is not the most useful pattern for what you're trying to do.  In particular, it seems like with your design, the widget-hierarchy can only be a straight line (with each widget having at most one decorator/child widget below it), whereas most GUIs fit more naturally with a branching-tree-structure, where each widget can hold (and serve as the "parent" of) any number of child widgets that represent other objects that are to be kept physically within the widget's geometric boundaries.

You might want to look at some other popular GUI APIs to see how they were designed -- in particular, I think Qt has a [pretty good design](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-index.html) -- a QWidgets-based-program's GUI consists of a tree of [QWidgets](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/widget-classes.html#the-widget-classes), with the z-ordering defined by the structure of the tree (child widgets's pixels render "in front of" their parents' pixels), and each widget's x/y/w/h layout/positioning within its parent-widget is managed by separate [QLayout](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html) objects.

Comment: So i'll have to implement a tree structure by myself , and place each class in its hierarchy? And while doing so i need to expose the client to this hierarchy , in case he will add another class ? i havent used this API , so i'll have to read about it a bit more(looks a bit complicated to me ;) .. ) . Thank you very much !

Comment: "tree structure" just means that each widget holds a list of child-widgets, but yes.  (Note that Qt's API is more complex because it wants to allow a lot of flexibility -- if your needs are simpler, you might be able to get away with a simpler API as well)

Answer (score 1):

> What if I want to enforce a creation order ?

You could specify it in the constructor by specifying compatible subclasses to decorate but it is really clumsy and goes against the idea of the decorators where clients can easily decorate "decorable" objects and where implementations of decorator can be added/removed without breaking the code. It echoes to the OPEN/CLOSED principle you quote.

> I thought about adding a member to each decorator-class marking its
>   hierarchy(such that objects with the same hierarchy cannot be created
>   together) in the displaying order but this seems like a bad solution
>   (Because I feel like its violating the OPEN/CLOSED principle)

It will duplicate/scatter rules of decoration in many decorator classes and it violates againts the OPEN/CLOSED principle : adding/removing/updating a decorator code may require change in many decorators.
I think that having a base class to represent gui items and specific kinds of items make sense but using the decorator will not be helpful since the rendering logic should be gathered and performed at a single place to make rules consistent and maintainable (one class to change).
I think that it should be a root gui item where you add the components in.
In this way, all rules would be applied to a single place when you do `RootUi.add(GuiItem)` or `RootUi.addAll(GuiItem...)`.
This pattern is the mediator.
Note that the mediator can split its logical in multiple processing classes if it makes things clearer.   For example a `BackgroundProcessing` class could handle the background, a `ForegroundProcessing` the foreground, another the overlay, and so for...

Comment: This seems like a nice solution and not so complicated . If i understood it correctly , i need to seperate each type of gui to a seperate interface (inheriting the GUI_ITEM).
How do i use this add method ? it needs to seperate different kind of GUI_ITEMs ?
This means each add method excepts different kind of interface ?